# Freezing first row and column of the dynamically generated table

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, html

I want to freeze the first row and first column of the dynamically generated table on click of a button, it is working fine for the first time, but once again when i click the same button all the data generated is inserted in the first column of the table which is freezed.
so how to resolve this problem and get data in same format as got output in the first click.

Code:

```
<div id="table_box" style="display: none; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; 
                                overflow-x: scroll; border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px ">
    <table id="cTable" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
    <tr id="table_data"></tr>   
    </table>
</div>


<style>
    .cTContainer { overflow: hidden; }
    .cTContainer table { table-layout: fixed; border-width: 0px; border: 0px solid #ebf4fb;  border-color: #b7ddf2;}
    .relativeContainer { position: relative; overflow: hidden;  }    
    .fixedTB { position: absolute; z-index: 11;  font-weight: bold; } 
    .fixedTB table tr td {overflow: hidden; background-color: #ebf4fb; }
    .leftContainer { position: absolute; overflow: hidden;  }
    .rightContainer { position: absolute; overflow: hidden;  }
    .leftSBWrapper { position: relative; z-index: 10; }
    .topSBWrapper { position: relative; z-index: 10; width: 100%; }
    .topSBWrapper table tr td {overflow: hidden;  background-color: #ebf4fb; font-weight: bold; }
    .SBWrapper { width: 100%; overflow: auto; }
   .cTContainer td { overflow: hidden; padding: 2px 2px; border-width: 1px; border: 1px solid #ebf4fb; border-color: #b7ddf2; }
   .leftContainer table tr { overflow: hidden;  background-color: #ebf4fb; }
    body { height: 600px; } 
</style>



<script>

    $('#view_data').submit(function() {

        var product = $('#product').val(); 
        var from = $('#from').val();
        var to = $('#to').val();

        var that = $(this),
        url = url,
        type = 'post',
        data = {
            product: product,
            from: from, 
            to: to
        };

        $("#LoadingImage").show();
        $('#table_box').hide();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {

                $('.toClear').remove();
                $('#table_data').empty();
                $('#table_data').append('<td width="10%" style="white-space: nowrap; text-align: center;">Reading time</td>');

                for (var key in response.product_name) 
                {
                    $('#table_data').append('<td style="white-space: nowrap; text-align: center;">'+response.product_name[key][0].product_name+'</td>');
                    $('.rightContainer').append('<td width="10%" style="white-space: nowrap; ">'+response.product_name[key][0].product_name+'</td>');
                }

                // Reverse the contents of the response, since javascripts inserts data from bottom...
                response.csv_final[0][0].reverse();

                for (var key in response.csv_final[0][0])
                {
                    var obj = response.csv_final[0][0][key];

                    $('#table_data').after('<tr class="row_'+key+' toClear">');

                    for (var key1 in obj)
                    {
                        data_out = obj[key1];
                        console.log(data_out);

                        if(data_out == null)
                        {
                            $('.row_'+key+'').append('<td style="white-space: nowrap; text-align: center;">'+'-');      

                        }else
                        {
                            $('.row_'+key+'').append('<td style="white-space: nowrap; text-align: center;">'+data_out); 
                        }
                    }
                    $('#table_data').append('</tr>');
                }

                $('#table_box').show();
                $("#LoadingImage").hide();

                //code for freezing first row and column of the table
                $(function () {
            $.fn.cTable = function(o) { 
            this.wrap('<div class="cTContainer" />');
            this.wrap('<div class="relativeContainer" />');            
            var origTableTmpl = '<table id="freeze" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="95%" ></table>'; 
            var row1 = this.find('tr').slice(0, o.fRows).clone();
            var r1c1ColSpan = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < o.fCols; i++ ) {
                r1c1ColSpan += this[0].rows[0].cells[i].colSpan;
            }

            //create table with just r1c1 which is fixed for both scrolls

            var tr1c1 = $(origTableTmpl);

            row1.each(function () {            
                var tdct = 0;
                $(this).find('td').filter( function () {
                    tdct += this.colSpan;
                    return tdct > r1c1ColSpan;
                }).remove();                
            });
            row1.appendTo(tr1c1);
            tr1c1.wrap('<div class="fixedTB" />');
            tr1c1.parent().prependTo(this.closest('.relativeContainer'));

            //create a table with just c1        
            var c1= this.clone().prop({'id': ''});
            alert('hello1');
            c1.find('tr').slice(0, o.fRows).remove();
            c1.find('tr').each(function (idx) {
                var c = 0; 
                $(this).find('td').filter(function () {
                    c += this.colSpan;
                    return c > r1c1ColSpan;
                }).remove();           
            });

            var prependRow = row1.first().clone();
            prependRow.find('td').remove();
           // prependRow.find('td').empty();
            c1.prepend(prependRow).wrap('<div class="leftSBWrapper" />')
            c1.parent().wrap('<div class="leftContainer" />');            
            c1.closest('.leftContainer').insertAfter('.fixedTB');

            //create table with just row 1 without col 1

            var r1 = $(origTableTmpl);
            row1 = this.find('tr').slice(0, o.fRows).clone();
            row1.each(function () {
                var tds = $(this).find('td'), tdct = 0;
                tds.filter (function () {
                    tdct += this.colSpan;
                    return tdct <= r1c1ColSpan;
                }).remove(); 
            });
            row1.appendTo(r1);

            r1.wrap('<div class="topSBWrapper" />')

            r1.parent().wrap('<div class="rightContainer" />')  

            r1.closest('.rightContainer').appendTo('.relativeContainer');

            $('.relativeContainer').css({'width': 'auto', 'height': o.height});

            this.wrap('<div class="SBWrapper"> ')        
            this.parent().appendTo('.rightContainer');    
            this.prop({'width': o.width});    

            var tw = 0;   
            //set width and height of rendered tables
            for (var i = 0; i < o.fCols; i++) {
                tw += $(this[0].rows[0].cells[i]).outerWidth(true);
            }
            tr1c1.width(tw);
            c1.width(tw);

            $('.rightContainer').css('left', tr1c1.outerWidth(true));

            for (var i = 0; i < o.fRows; i++) {
                var tr1c1Ht = $(c1[0].rows[i]).outerHeight(true);
                var thisHt = $(this[0].rows[i]).outerHeight(true);
                var finHt = (tr1c1Ht > thisHt)?tr1c1Ht:thisHt;
                $(tr1c1[0].rows[i]).height(finHt);
                $(r1[0].rows[i]).height(finHt);
            }
            $('.leftContainer').css({'top': tr1c1.outerHeight(true), 'width': tr1c1.outerWidth(true)});

            var rtw = $('.relativeContainer').width() - tw;
            $('.rightContainer').css({'width' : rtw, 'height': o.height, 'max-width': o.width - tw});    

            var trs = this.find('tr');
            trs.slice(1, o.fRows).remove();

            trs.slice(0, 1).find('td').remove();
            trs.each(function () {
                var c = 0; 
                $(this).find('td').filter(function () {
                    c += this.colSpan;
                    return c <= r1c1ColSpan;
                }).remove(); 
            });

            r1.width(this.outerWidth(true));

            for (var i = 1; i < c1[0].rows.length; i++) {
                var c1Ht = $(c1[0].rows[i]).outerHeight(true);
                var thisHt = $(this[0].rows[i]).outerHeight(true);
                var finHt = (c1Ht > thisHt)?c1Ht:thisHt;
                $(c1[0].rows[i]).height(finHt);
                $(this[0].rows[i]).height(finHt);
            }

            $('.SBWrapper').css({'height': $('.relativeContainer').height() - $('.topSBWrapper').height()});            

            $('.SBWrapper').scroll(function () {
                var rc = $(this).closest('.relativeContainer');
                var lfW = rc.find('.leftSBWrapper');
                var tpW = rc.find('.topSBWrapper');

                lfW.css('top', ($(this).scrollTop()*-1));
                tpW.css('left', ($(this).scrollLeft()*-1));      
            });

           $(window).resize(function () {
                $('.rightContainer').width(function () {
                    return $(this).closest('.relativeContainer').outerWidth() - $(this).siblings('.leftContainer').outerWidth();
                });

            });

        }

        $('#cTable').cTable({

            width: 1300,
            height: 500,
            fCols: 1,
            fRows: 1
        });
    });

            }
        });
        return false;
    });             



});
</script>
```

sorry i cant post images since i have less 10 reputation , please give your email id so that i will send through that.. thank you...

Comment: please put your code into jsfiddle or plunker...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YMvk9/656/

Comment: the values are retrieved from database, i hope without values it wont work, let  me know how to run this in jsfiddle...